# Redirect non-www url to www url in zend framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework

I am trying to redirect non-www utl to www url actually I successfully did it.

I have urls for internal pages like kieserdesign.com/index/portfolio

The problem is that when page redirects from kieserdesign.com/index/portfolio for a www url it is redirecting to www.kieserdesign.com/index.php/portfolio but it should be www.kieserdesign.com/index/portfolio

I am using the following rule for non-www url to www url

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

my current .htaccess is in public/

```
# Rewrite rules for Zend Framework
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php

# Security: Don't allow browsing of directories
Options -Indexes
# PHP settings
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag register_globals off
php_flag short_open_tag on
```

Please guide me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To Redirect WWW Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule !\.(pdf|php|js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css|rss|zip|tar\.gz)$ index.php
```

As per your desc. I have change the code. Now check it.